# Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I unexpectedly encountered the following error while trying to run my application:

```
Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

Below is the log cat:

```
11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:698)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at com.dooba.beta.ThirdFragment.onCreateView(ThirdFragment.java:15)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    11-09 13:11:58.558: E/AndroidRuntime(12542):    ... 19 more
```

Below is the java code:

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_city, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Below is the layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >
    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
       >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" 

            />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: UPDATE, now you should use androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Resolve : Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49512242/how-to-resolve-error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-cardview)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I solved this by adding updated cardview and appcompat on the app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'    
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
    }
```

Then rebuild the project

Comment: Fixes [CircularReveal](https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) error

Answer (score 24):

the issue can also be caused by using the `androidX`
try to change to `<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView` and the crashing should be ok.
One tip, check if you see the layout in the preview.

in the gradle it shoud be like : 
   `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'`

Answer (score 9):

Just locate your cardview layout in your xml file, for example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView......</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and replace it with

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView.......</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify a dependency on the [v7 cardview library](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-cardview)

Edit build.gradle and specify "com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+" in the dependencies section.

Answer (score 4):

Answers above didn't help. Works fine after adding

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    ...
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">
```

Can't explain.

Comment: Yes it happened, change **app:cardBackgroundColor="?cardBackgroundColor"** to **app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"**

Answer (score 4):

This error is caused because you are probably using AndroidX but you are using this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Change to AndroidX CardView dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

and change your class into the layout:

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem .
first you must add cardview from the

1. Close the main project.
2. Remove the android-support-v7-appcompat .
3. Restart the Eclipse.
4. Add the  android-support-v7-appcompat .
5. Build the project.
6. Then open the main project and build all the three projects.
7. The error still remains. Restart eclipse. That's it.

That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If this error happened in AndroidX, you need to use following dependencies to fix this error:

```
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is with your dependencies

try this read every step carefully

https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res

Answer (score 0):

While checking all your dependency just check the related JAVA class file that is it **extends AppCompatACtivity** or not.
Sure this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error because you may have copied the code from a web page and pasted it as it is in your project especially in layouts. Please don't do that and if you do that you should see the design part if it is OK or not.I also got the same error and solved it by implementing by myself.