# How to solve the issue "Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView"?

Tags: android, listview, fragment, cardview

This is sure will a duplicate of [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833517/error-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-cardview) question.but I'm still unable to find the solution even crawling over the internet.I want to set the `category` in the `Cate_layout` by either using `ArrayAdapter` or `someCustomAdapter`(I have tried both, but no success :( )
This is the Logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: tomestore.wixsite.com.tome, PID: 14405
>                                                                               android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I have a fragment BookFragment

```
public class BookFragment extends Fragment {


ListView listView;
String[] something ={"something", " nothing"};
public BookFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_book, container, false);
    listView = view.findViewById(R.id.cateSlit);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.cate_layout,R.id.catagory,something));
    return view;
}
```

And this is cate_layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/container_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/catagory"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Category" />

            .........

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And Here is the fragment_book

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="tomestore.wixsite.com.tome.BookFragment">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/cateSlit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tomestore.wixsite.com.tome"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        } 
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

// RecyclerView
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

// CardView
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: did you add `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'`

Comment: yup `implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0` here it is

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Instead of this

```
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```